# tsql dynamic table stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

I wrote a long list of stored procedure to update some tables, when finished I realized that most of this stored procedure were very similar each other.. with only few fields changing

then I was wondering to make a single stored procedure and this is what I did:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Save_All
(
    @UID            nvarchar(100)   = NULL,  --All
    @Table          nvarchar(40)    = NULL, --All
    @ID             int             = 0,        --All
    ...
    @SubCategory    nvarchar(50)    = NULL, --              Ticker
    @Link           nvarchar(300)   = NULL  --              Ticker
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    DECLARE @S      nvarchar(max)='',
            @P      nvarchar(max)='',
            @cols1  nvarchar(max)='',
            @cols2  nvarchar(max)='',
            @cols3  nvarchar(max)=''

    SELECT @cols1= ISNULL(@cols1 + ',','') + QUOTENAME(name) 
        FROM (SELECT top (100) name  FROM sys.columns  
        WHERE id=OBJECT_ID(@Table) and name<>'ID' Order by colID) AS Columns; 
    SELECT @cols2= ISNULL(@cols2 + ',','') + '@_' + name 
        FROM (SELECT top (100) name  FROM sys.columns  
        WHERE id=OBJECT_ID(@Table) and name<>'ID' Order by colID) AS Columns; 
    SELECT @cols3= ISNULL(@cols3 + ',','') + QUOTENAME(name)+'=@_'+ name   
        FROM (SELECT top (100) name  FROM sys.columns  
        WHERE id=OBJECT_ID(@Table) and name<>'ID' Order by colID) AS Columns; 

    SELECT @cols1 = STUFF(@cols1, 1, 1, '');
    SELECT @cols2 = STUFF(@cols2, 1, 1, '');
    SELECT @cols3 = STUFF(@cols3, 1, 1, '');

    IF (@ID=0 OR @ID is null) 
        SET @S = N'INSERT INTO @_Table ('+ @cols1 + ') VALUES ('+@cols2+')' 
    ELSE
        SET @S = N' UPDATE @_Table SET ' +@cols3 +' WHERE ID=@_ID' 

    --PRINT @S

    SET @P=  '@_UID                 nvarchar(100),
              @_Table               nvarchar(40),
              @_ID                  int,
              ...
              @_SubCategory         nvarchar(50),
              @_Link                nvarchar(300)'

    EXEC sp_executesql @S,@P,@UID,@Table,@ID,...,@SubCategory,@Link
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

But, although the list of parameters is quite long (I amended most of them in the example) it does not include all fields of all the tables and therefore return an error in many cases..

Solution would be to include in @cols1/2/3 only the fields that are defined also as parameter.. or to set to null the relative @_xx

But this is beyond my current knowledge..

By the way.. what about the stored procedure? which unacceptable mistakes does it contain?

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: You should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also, from SQL Server **2005** onwards, it is recommend to use the system catalog views in the `sys` schema - e.g. `sys.columns` - instead of the old, soon-to-be-deprecated `syscolumns` view.

Comment: ok well noted.. I amend immedediately

Comment: I cant see where do you update @_ID? This doesn't make sense WHERE ID=@_ID if @_ID is always 0 or am i wrong?

Comment: `@ID` is an input parameter, that's identity column: if it is 0 will insert since does not exist 0 column, if it is bigger than 0 it upgrades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution and was easier than thought..

moved
    @P definition on top and add

```
SET @P= '...'
```

on top and add

```
AND CHARINDEX('@_'+name+' ',@P)>0
```

to the rules to create the 3

```
@cols
```

All together:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Save_All
(
@UID            nvarchar(100)   = NULL, --All
@Table          nvarchar(40)    = NULL, --All
@ID             int             = 0,    --All
...
@SubCategory    nvarchar(50)    = NULL, --              Ticker
@Link           nvarchar(300)   = NULL  --              Ticker
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    DECLARE @S      nvarchar(max)='',
            @P      nvarchar(max)='',
            @cols1  nvarchar(max)='',
            @cols2  nvarchar(max)='',
            @cols3  nvarchar(max)=''

    SET @P=  '@_UID                 nvarchar(100),
              @_Table               nvarchar(40),
              @_ID                  int,
              ...
              @_SubCategory         nvarchar(50),
              @_Link                nvarchar(300)'

    SELECT @cols1= ISNULL(@cols1 + ',','') + QUOTENAME(name) 
        FROM (SELECT top (100) name  FROM sys.columns  
        WHERE id=OBJECT_ID(@Table) and name<>'ID' 
        AND CHARINDEX('@_'+name+' ',@P)>0 Order by colID) AS Columns; 
    SELECT @cols2= ISNULL(@cols2 + ',','') + '@_' + name 
        FROM (SELECT top (100) name  FROM sys.columns  
        WHERE id=OBJECT_ID(@Table) and name<>'ID' 
        AND CHARINDEX('@_'+name+' ',@P)>0Order by colID) AS Columns; 
    SELECT @cols3= ISNULL(@cols3 + ',','') + QUOTENAME(name)+'=@_'+ name   
        FROM (SELECT top (100) name  FROM sys.columns  
        WHERE id=OBJECT_ID(@Table) and name<>'ID' 
        AND CHARINDEX('@_'+name+' ',@P)>0Order by colID) AS Columns; 

    SELECT @cols1 = STUFF(@cols1, 1, 1, '');
    SELECT @cols2 = STUFF(@cols2, 1, 1, '');
    SELECT @cols3 = STUFF(@cols3, 1, 1, '');

    IF (@ID=0 OR @ID is null) 
        SET @S = N'INSERT INTO @_Table ('+ @cols1 + ') VALUES ('+@cols2+')' 
    ELSE
        SET @S = N' UPDATE @_Table SET ' +@cols3 +' WHERE ID=@_ID' 

    --PRINT @S

    EXEC sp_executesql @S,@P,@UID,@Table,@ID,...,@SubCategory,@Link
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

well, a little rough.. surely there are better way to build it but so far.. seems it work well

thanks everybody for reading!
Joe